# How do I tell screen readers that data-content should be read?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover, custom-data-attribute, screen-readers

Having **bootstrap popover** setup to work with HTML data what is a good way to tell screen readers that the content encoded inside data-content is something that needs to be read when user triggers a click on the link.

Here's the code:

```
<a href="#" data-content="&lt;table&gt;
&lt;tbody&gt;
&lt;tr&gt;
&lt;td&gt;User 1&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td&gt;User 2&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;/tbody&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;">Contact Us</a>
```

As you see in order to show HTML the content needs to be encoded but I am not sure how the screen reader will handle this. Is this even considered good practice?

I could switch to a solution that has all the popover content as real HTML code somewhere down the page ad target them with IDs. Will this be a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about it a huge amount, you can add `aria-label="User 1, User 2"` or choose the best attribute to use yourself [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/aria/aria.html#aria-attrs-all).

Comment: That will become in some cases a multi contact table or some other thing with links maybe images so I am not sure how that will work. Looking at the aria attributes maybe something like aria-tooltip and aria-expanded will work.